# Antimatter conundrum

Tags: antimatter

Why are matter and antimatter not coming into contact within our atmosphere or within close proximity to earth. Obviously I understand the meeting would be catastrophic but why does it only happen in distant galaxies. Please excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antimatter is very rare in our universe as it mostly contains normal matter. It is also *not* true that only distant galaxies produce antimatter. There is antimatter in our galaxy too. The fact is that there is **so much more** matter that the distribution of antimatter is vastly spread out and although they may be *produced*, antimatter does not *stay* antimatter for significant times as there is so much matter around( they collide with matter again to form gamma rays). Thus altogether they don't pose a threat as there is so little of it around that finally reaches earth.

This link below is an article about antimatter detection in our own galaxy. Together in cosmic rays we also get antimatter detection but it makes up less than 1% of cosmic rays and cosmic rays are the collection of the stream of particles from the *entire* universe. So thus you can grasp the situation here.

[Antimatter in our Galaxy](https://arstechnica.com/science/2017/05/explaining-why-our-galaxy-produces-so-much-antimatter/)

Comment: Thanks again for the response . It makes sense finally. It's happening all the time but in tiny amounts . Simple when you know.

Answer (score 0):

Despite being relatively rare compared to matter, antimatter is all around us, as a result of cosmic ray particle showers. A very small proportion of cosmic rays are positrons, but mainly they are baryons. They hit the atmosphere and form cascades of particle-antiparticle pairs, the antiparticles annihilate with other particles making more pairs, and so on. Antiparticles are hitting your body almost every second.

Because of baryogenesis, the production of matter over antimatter early in the universe, we don't expect distant galaxies to be different. Although given the assymetry is not fully explained one possibile reason for could be https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon_asymmetry#Regions_of_the_universe_where_antimatter_dominates

Answer (score 0):

Antimatter is produced via high energy particle collisions. The Sun produces 80 Tons of antimatter a day, but upon exiting the star; it typically Annihilates upon contact other solar particle emissions or random stellar dust in interplanetary medium and matter producing gamma ray photons detected by various telescopes.
[image]

Astrobiological Life scientists are enamoured by gamma rays, to find suitable stars for life. Stars with unusally strong gamma emissions can be eliminated as candidates for hosting planets with habitable life.